# Unreal Engine + VS Rus = иероглифы при ошибках компиляции

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine-4

Проблема в том, что установил русскую версию VS, и при компиляции в UE4 выдаются ошибки в иероглифах. 
Переустановка VS на английскую версию не помогла. Теперь наблюдаю вопросики и странные квадратики вместо адекватного текста.
Как решить - не нашел =(

Answer (score 1):

Решение простое - путь к проекту и к редактору `UE` должен содержать **только латинские символы и цифры**, при наличии русских букв в адресе всё крешилось.

*У меня стоит русская версия `VS`, проблема была такой же.*